# Download an image from a website into a CouchDB attachment through Rails without local storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb, mechanize, rest-client

I'm trying to scrape some websites and store the images as CouchDB attachments.
In order to expedite the process I don't want to store the images locally at all.

The relevant gems I'm already using are Mechanize, CouchRest Model and rest-client.
I'm also using the Ruby URI module.

I tried feeding the exact file URL into CouchRest's create_attachment method.
However, I believe it expects a file of Ruby class File. (It's not clearly documented.) And it throws an undefined method error for path. (A File method)

In the below code, address is a URI array for the page and @string_address is a string version of the same.

```
def scrape_site
  agent = Mechanize.new
  page = agent.get @string_address
  page.images.each do |image|
    image_src = address
    image_src[5] = URI.split(image.src)[5]
    image_src = URI::HTTP.new(*image_src).to_s
    self.create_attachment file: image_src, name: image.text
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it requires a File object, you just need to make one that pretends it's one... try creating a class that subclasses StringIO. Construct it to the binary data of the image URL, and just add a path? method that returns something that will (hopefully) satisfy CouchRest.